# while generating insert script as dynamic query, this N is not getting prefixed even though the column is nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO test ( name ) 
VALUES ( '''+S1.name+''' )' from SourceTable S1
```

while generating insert script as dynamic query, the unicode chararacter N is not getting prefixed even though the column is nvarchar.

Insert without dynamic query worked well by prefixing N.

Answer (score 5):

Since a non-Latin1 character is included, you need unicode `N`-literal.

```
insert into [test] select N'―    menu1;'
```

Comment: @Cedersved, exactly!

Comment: It worked, Thank you.. Now the real issue is, while generating insert script  as dynamic query, this N is not getting prefixed even though the column is nvarchar. SELECT 
 'INSERT INTO test
  (
   name
  )
  VALUES
  ( 
   '''+S1.name+'''
  )'
 from SourceTable S1

Comment: `SELECT N'INSERT ...`?

Comment: SELECT N'INSERT ...?- not worked unfortunately..                                       
   SELECT 
  N'UPDATE [test] SET name='''+name+'updated' + '''' FROM 
  [test]

Answer (score 0):

Add N along with column name just after the equal sign, silly solution but took my time due to over thinking lol...

```
SELECT  'UPDATE [test] SET name=N'''+name+'updated' + ''''
    FROM    [test]
```